# RegEx: recombine matched groups to new string

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to parse a list of strings if they match a RegEx-expression (with groups) and if it does, recombine the groups to a new string.

Say I got files like

```
file_1.csv
file_2a.csv
file_3.csv
```

Using (file)_(\d).csv I could match first and last only, no problem.

Now my goal is to reassemble the groups again in a new order. I want to provide something like $2$1.csv, giving me

```
1file.csv
3file.csv
```

Is this also part of methods provided in the RegEx-class of the framework? Or is that something I need to parse myself? I was not able to find a method where I can supply the string with the group numbers and get my result back.

---

RegEx.Replace is not the function I am looking for I think? Or is it?
I can put in $2$1 as replacement, and it actually delivers exact what I need.

But that only works if the pattern matches the whole expressions (and replace "starts on empty string")

Additionally, I need to first check using .IsMatch(...) if it is a valid file to match in the first place, because otherwise the replace matches nothing and delivers back 1:1 the original expression.

---

I guess I am looking for a method on the framework where I use the Match-collection delivered by RegEx.Match and "apply" the group info to the new pattern string "$1$2$3"

Thanks!

*edit: The regex pattern as well as the recombination pattern need to be dynamic and user provided. Obviously they need to be compatible with each other.

Comment: What would be a valid file?what would isMatch be?

Comment: Valid files are all those that match the pattern provided (in this example first and last). bool System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.IsMatch(string pattern, string expression) is a static method to deliver if... it is a match or not.

Comment: Do you really wish to ignore file_2a.csv from the same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach. I tweaked your Regex and replacement string to include the file extension.

```
var files = new List<string> { "file_1.csv", "file_2a.csv", "file_3.csv" };
var regex = new Regex("(file)_(\\d)(.csv)");
var replacement = "$2$1$3";

foreach (var f in files ){
    if (regex.IsMatch(f)){
        Console.WriteLine( regex.Replace(f, replacement ) );
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
1file.csv
3file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] fileNames = { "file_1.csv", "file_2a.csv", "file_3.csv" };            
    string[] newFileNames = fileNames.Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"^(file)_(\d)\.csv$")).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < newFileNames.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] temp = newFileNames[i].Split('.');
        newFileNames[i] = temp[0].Replace("file_", "") + "file.csv";
        Console.WriteLine(newFileNames[i]);
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZOHg.png)

Comment: Remove the screen shot, it is hard to look at..we can trust that the code has the results you suggest as a textual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use named match captures for the extraction/replacement here is an example (*note that .Dump is used by Linqpad to show current state of instances* used in the example results below)

```
string text = @"file1.csv";

var pattern = @"(?<FileName>[^\d_]+)(?:_?)(?<Number>[^.]+).csv";

var parts = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select (mt => new
                 {
                    Name = mt.Groups["FileName"].Value,
                    Num  = mt.Groups["Number"].Value
                 }).Dump();


Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "${Number}${FileName}.csv").Dump();
```

Here is the result of the dumps, the first a dynamic entity with two fields of Name and Num and the second the output from Regex.Replace:

[image: Results of the Dump calls]

I leave it up to you on matching the extension, but this shows the how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution that seems pretty elegant to me.
You have to use the C# String.format style though.

Note that this code is only for a single replacement (loop missing) (but fits the title)

```
string in = "file_1.csv",
  regex = "(file)_(\d).csv",
  template = "{2}{1}.csv";

// get group content of first match as string array
string[] groups = Regex.Matches(in, regex)[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
// format according to template
string result = String.Format(template, groups);
```

I hope this helps some people searching for this (it's a lot more flexible)